# Need help installing Visual C++ 2015 64-bit 14.0.23918 redistributable package

Tags: visual-c++

Disclaimer, I'm a huge noob when it comes to coding and I've been struggling, but learning, with nuget and powershell.

Thing is, whenever I try the microsoft installer for the VC++ redist I get Error:

> 0x80096010 - The digital signature of the object did not verify

So I started looking at alternatives.

It's been days since this ordeal began, 4 forums and 2 tech supports later I found this package https://chocolatey.org/packages/vcredist2015 that is exactly what I am looking for, but have no idea how to install it without Visual Studio (which I also can't install).

I would highly appreciate anyone with some free time to lend me a hand.

Comment: You don't need to install the redistributables separately. Install VS 2015.

Comment: Are you actually trying to program something or get the redist installed for some other purpose?  
If you can't install the redist or visual studio either, then you have serious problem on your hands. It's probably time for a reformat.
Google also suggests make sure your system date isn't wrong and youre fully systemupdated; and disable or uninstall your security software.